# Firefox Extension: Showing + Hidding AutoCompleteRichResult

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

Setting any of

```
document.getElementById('PopupAutoCompleteRichResult').setAttribute('hidden', true)                                         
document.getElementById('PopupAutoCompleteRichResult').hidden = true
document.getElementById('PopupAutoCompleteRichResult').setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');`
```

hides the AutoComplete Popup.

But how do I show it again? Neither `display: -moz-popup` nor `hidden = false` works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also unable to get the AutoComplete Popup back after hiding it. But depending on your specific requirement, another possible solution is to simply disable/enable the bar through the preferences. Here's a very simple proof-of concept I wrote that toggles availability of the bar every 10 seconds:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService)
                    .getBranch("browser.urlbar.autocomplete.");
    window.setInterval(function() {
        prefs.setBoolPref("enabled", !prefs.getBoolPref("enabled"));
    }, 10000);
}, false);
```

Comment: you rock, thank you so much!! - we mixed up statt Prefs.setCharPref('browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled', !!display); vs Prefs.setBoolPref('browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled', !!display);

Answer (score 0):

You might be having this problem:

> Using setAttribute() to modify certain
>   attributes, most notably value in XUL,
>   works inconsistently, as the attribute
>   specifies the default value. To access
>   or modify the current values, you
>   should use the properties. For
>   example, use elt.value instead of
>   elt.setAttribute('value', val).

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute#Notes
- http://xulsolutions.blogspot.com/2006/07/attributes-and-properties-essential.html

Comment: thank you lwburk, i tried this, too ... but it didn't work out :/

Comment: @Lukas - Same here. I'll leave this answer so that anyone else struggling with this issue in the future can rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be showing and hiding the autocomplete popup, the autocomplete widget handles that for the user. In particular it's likely to get confused if it's not shown as the result of an autocompletion operation.

Comment: that's why i deactivate it only under special circumstances and would like to activate it afterwards. - reason i need to do it is a focus bug in mozilla firefox: from the source: // XXXblake Proper fix is to just check whether focus is in the urlbar. However, focus with the autocomplete widget is all
1328     // hacky and broken and there's no way to do that right now. So this just patches it to ensure that alt+enter works when focus

Comment: @Lukas as usual that code was checked in without any sort of explanation as to what it was trying to do and why it was doing it. And that particular block of code was removed in Firefox 3, so I'm none the wiser as to what you're trying to achieve.